# Ищу метод обработки изображений для диплома

Tags: c++, cuda, обработка-изображений

Назрел дипломный проект. С руководителем решили использовать CUDA и с помощью него оптимизировать что-нибудь со сложными вычислениями. Со стороны вычислений для оптимизации решили взять какой-нибудь метод обработки изображений. Рыщу в интернете и не могу найти что-то дельное, потому что до этого я с этим не разбирался.

Может, кто-нибудь знает какую-нибудь библиотеку для обработки изображений и "тяжелый" метод в ней, который можно было бы оптимизировать? Так же можно и любой другой "тяжелый" метод (не обязательно в обработке изображений).
Библиотека нужна не та, которая уже оптимизировалась многократно, естественно.
Код желателен на C++ (не знаю, возможен ли другой вариант для CUDA).

Comment: Прекрасно себя ведём: минуснул анонимненько и отвалил.

Comment: "минуснул"? Не совсем понял.

Comment: Это я не про Вас. Я-то восстановил справедливость, поэтому сейчас оценка 0.

Comment: Большое спасибо за справедливость.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Навскидку, есть такой проект [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) - конвертит и преобразовывает картинки в разных видах. У нее есть ответвление - [graphicMagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/), где пытались ее "дооптимизировать". Код там с/с++, так что все будет понятно. Что можно делать - пропробовать улучшить resize картинок.

Второй проект - [opencv](https://opencv.org/) - это с области работы с изображением и видео. Там все можно смотреть и пробовать.

Третье - [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) - обработка видео. Тут можно много чего. Банально - наложение фильтра на изображение или подчистить водяной знак.

Comment: Спасибо за примеры. Я правильно понимаю, что под "улучшить resize" и в двух других проектах Вы все еще говорите про распараллеливание вычислений при помощи CUDA (то есть улучшение быстродействия), а не про доработку алгоритма для улучшения результата на выходе? Потому что я пока планирую только быстродействием заняться.

Comment: да, я имел ввиду как раз улучшить скорость. А вот улучшить качество, это тема большого отдельного исследования.